# UIButton image in tvOS stretched when button is focused

Tags: tvos

I am developing tvos application. I observed that button image is stretched when the button is focused.[image]

Play icon in the button is round.

Comment: Explore its properties with the view hierarchy inspector.

Comment: I tried setting   self.button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentFill;
    self.button.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill;
    self.button.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; But still imageview in view inspector shows scaletofill when button is focused

Comment: Did you try inspecting the view's frame with the view hierarchy inspector when it's focused and when it's not? Right now you don't know what's going wrong, and neither do we, so there's nothing we can do to help you unless you gather more information. Like by using the view hierarchy inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Make the aspect ratio "Aspect fit" in the attributes inspector tab from the storyboard.

Comment: I tried but still it shows oval shape when tvos button is focused

Comment: Better implementation will be using button over image.